# Live references in comments in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

There's `Copy reference` option in PhpStorm, generates string pointer to the particular line, eg.

```
src/index.html:67
```

I'd like to use this reference string in `@see` comment.

Is there any option to have this:

- to be clickable (this works well, when reference is e.g. a class, not a particular line)
- to be automatically updated (line number), when referenced code moves?

Comment: There is no such line-specific referencing functionality in IDE (except bookmarks perhaps) that would match your requirements, especially the 2nd one (requires updating all reference files if line is moved in the referenced one -- pretty unexpected behaviour for possible simple move line up/down change).

Comment: It is better to make reference to the methods. Reference to the line is useless when we change the code.

Comment: @funivan And how to reference particular rules in CSS files then?